# model doesn't move with rig

Tags: rigify

I rig a model with Rigify and paint the weight to test the animation. Everything was fine.
[image] But when I change to object mode to move my character his body doesn't move with the rigs.[image]
Only the body has this issue.
Also, I use 3.0 so I can't upload this file

Comment: select body + rig, then Ctrl+P > parent with automatic weights?

Comment: yes, it works. but the weight was gone, I have to paint the weight again.

Comment: when you already weight painted the body and want to keep the weights then just choose Ctrl+P > *with empty groups*

Comment: What do you mean "I use 3.0 so I can't upload this file"?

Comment: because sometimes people want me to upload my file. but 3,0 likes can't upload.

Comment: "3,0 likes can't upload"... Sorry, I also don't understand. You can zip any file and upload it.

Comment: When you parent with automatic weights do you get "Bone heat weighting error"?
Or maybe the body object is constrained? 
It's really hard to say without looking at the file